# Why don't the Alt+num Firefox keyboard shortcuts work?

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys

There is problem in Firefox 4.x with Alt+num shortcut (switching between tabs) - it just doesn't work.
I'm not sure if this is a problem with my Ubuntu installation (11.04 upgraded from 10.10) or this is common problem.

With chromium Alt+num shortcuts work.

Comment: Solved: the same shotcuts was used by Nextplease addon. After removing nextplease addon, Alt+num shorcuts works.

Comment: Post an answer with your solution and, using check mark that appears on the left, mark it solved.

Answer (score 1):

This question was solved by the OP:

> Solved: the same shotcuts was used by Nextplease addon.
>    After removing nextplease addon, Alt+num shorcuts works.